# Highcharts chart re-render

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to display a series of data in a form of chart. I am displaying the data into three chart formats - Area chart, Line chart and Bar chart. Defaulty the page will load to Area chart, On button click I will load the line chart and Bar chart respectively. When I change my chart type with a button click, the chart width increases by 25px exactly.

Is there any method in highcharts to re-render the graph. I hope by re-rendering I can fix this Issue. Because I used timeout to clear and re-render the DOM. But timeout is not the good way to do that. So If there is any re-render method in highcharts, Kindly share.

Comment: Explore the chart instance api [docs](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart); you may consider [chart.redraw](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#redraw) [chart.reflow](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow), [chart.update](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update), or the more radical [chart.destroy](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#destroy) if you want to reuse the container.

Answer (score 0):

Changing a chart's type should not affect on chart's dimensions - please check: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0mrn3qLd/

Maybe some of your options are different during updates?

However, if you need to recreate the chart, it is enough to create a new one in the same container - for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/40tu35ca/

```
document.getElementById('area').addEventListener('click', function() {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {...});
});

document.getElementById('line').addEventListener('click', function() {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {...});
});
```

You can force the wrapper component to rerender if you are using Angular.